# Simple assignment of a variable to string function

Tags: c++, string, stringindexoutofbounds

I am brand new in programming. I keep getting the error  `what():  basic_string::at: __n` *(which is 14)* `>= this->size()` *(which is 14)*

```
void longword(string word) {
    int length = word.length();
    if (length > 10)
    {
        cout << word[0] << length << word[length];
    }
    else
    {
        cout << word;
    }
}

int main() {
    string word;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for (int a = 0; a < n; a++)
    {
        cin >> word;
        longword(word);
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Indices are [0...length), e.g. the last index is `length - 1`, so `word[length]` is out of bounds.

Comment: If you want the first and last element you can also use `word.front()` and `word.back()`, which are safe meanwhile `word.size() > 0`.

Answer (score 2):

`word[length]` is out of bounds. `word[length-1]` will give you the last character in the word.

Comment: Technically, as explained in [std::string documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at), if you try to access the element at index of `length`, you will get the reference to the null character returned.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Only in C++20, as it seems. This implies that we will not be able to use it during our life times if we want to write a portable program.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Where did you see, that it is since C++20? Are we reading the same documentation? Since I read it from a section tagged with "since C++11".

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius You are right, I mis-read the table (which I find somewhat confusing, it combines changes in the return type (with C++20) with changes in the semantics (which happened with C++11).